# How to solve the error of Error(25,13) in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I have tried to add a dependency in the gradle.build file :-

```
compile 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.2'
```

but i am constantly getting the `Error(25,13) :failed to resolve` . I have tried solving it using a few techniques like adding the dependency from the BUILD menu also but the problem still persists.I have tried restarting and validating caches too. Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Comment: Have you made sure that what you are trying to add actually exists?

Comment: ofcourse ..i got the link here... https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview